# How to export a function type?

Tags: typescript

This is how I export and import typescript interface for objects. Everything works just fine. Giving this as an example of what I'm trying to achieve, but with functions.

**Module 1**

```
export interface MyInterface {
  property: string;
}
```

**Module 2**

```
import {MyInterface} from './module1';

const object: MyInterface = {
    property: 'some value'
};
```

---

The code below gives me an error "TS2304: Cannot find name 'myFunction'". How do I export and import a function type?

**Module 1**

```
export let myFunction: (argument: string) => void;
```

**Module 2**

```
import {myFunction} from './module1';

let someFunction: myFunction;
```

Comment: `export type myFunction = (arg: string) => void` ?

Comment: @Gerrit0, woohoo! Thank you sir! It works! So simple!

Comment: @Gerrit0 please make an answer out of your comment, so other people know as well.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is how it's done:

**Module 1**

```
export type myFunction = (arg: string) => void
```

**Module 2**

```
import {myFunction} from './module1';

let someFunction: myFunction;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you need a **return type** of the function type as well, you should create it in the following manner (as explained in the [TypeScript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types)):

### Module 1

```
export interface myFunction {
    (argument: string): boolean;
}
```

### Module 2

```
import {myFunction} from './module1';

let someFunction: myFunction; 
let result = someFunction("hello");
```