# declare function that adheres to type

Tags: typescript, typescript-definitions

So I've got a non-typescript project that I'm writing a definition file for.

I've got something that looks like this:

```
type SomeType<S> = <T>(operator: (arg: T) => void) => S
```

and I want to export a function that adheres to that type in the definition file, but I'm not sure how to do it. I tried this, but of course the syntax isn't correct:

```
type SomeType<S> = <T>(operator: (arg: T) => void) => S

export function someFunc<S> = SomeType<S>
```

Possible?

Comment: "... some type definition" If you leave out part of your code, please replace it with **actual working code** that can make your program run in order to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is there any reason why you have to have `SomeType` as a type alias and not just declare the function type directly?

Comment: @Aplet123 - yes! Because I need to have <S> be a required generic, but T needs to be inferred. If I write `declare function someFunc<S,T>(...)` then I can't get it to infer `T` when I supply `S` - I have to either supply all or none.

Comment: Does it have to be exported as a function? Else this should work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931361/how-to-export-a-function-type